get lookup items as 'Defaultitems' in DropdownCanvas field power apps
i am trying to use Lookup function in the deaultselecteditems field of Dropdowncanvas, i am getting an error saying "Expected a table value".
not sure how do i get my column values as deaultselecteditems  in DropdownCanvas .
POwer app lookup error

Put the entire formula in a Table function like - Table({Value: LookUp(  )})
